# How to disallow local URLs for file_get_contents() in PHP?

Tags: php, url, localhost, file-get-contents

I want to read a web page with [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) by a user given URL (unsafe!). I want to disallow reading local resources (files, web pages, …). How can I deny accessing the local server by `file_get_contents()`?

I tried the following code, but it is not enough, obviously (many names can map to IPv4 and IPv6 loopbacks).

```php
// URL from some web form; unsafe because user filled
$url = 'http://localhostXYZ/';

if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false || preg_match('%^https?://%im', $url) === 0)
            throw new Exception('Invalid URL.');

// do not allow localhost URLs (not complete!)
$components = parse_url($url);
if (empty($components['host']))
    throw new Exception('No relative URLs allowed.');
if (strcasecmp($components['host'], 'localhost') === 0 ||
    strcasecmp($components['host'], '127.0.0.1' ) === 0 ||
    strcasecmp($components['host'], '[::1]' ) === 0)
    throw new Exception('Localhost URLs allowed.');

// create a stream
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' =>
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0\r\n" .
            "Accept: text/html\r\n" .
            "Accept-language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3\r\n" .
            "Referer: https://test.test/\r\n"
    )
);

// open URL
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

set_error_handler(function () {
    throw new Exception('Cannot read URL.');
}, E_WARNING);
// open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context, 0, self::MaxContentLength);
restore_error_handler();

if ($file === false)
    throw new Exception('Cannot read URL.');
```

Comment: Configure your webserver such that it doesn't respond to arbitrary Host headers (that's best practice in general, independent of the problem here). Making a blacklist is then trivial (and impossible if you don't change your webserver config, because I can create as many domains as I want that point to 127.0.0.1). How to configure your webserver appropriately depends on the particular webserver you're using and is off-topic on SO. Try [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) if you need help.

Comment: @Peter, thank you! In general you are right (my Apache2 denies unknown domains already). But that’s not the point here. What if the code is part of a web application that will be release to public and therefore has no control over the web server config? I guess, I have to resolve the domain name `gethostbyname()` and test if the IP address is local (however this works in detail).

Comment: DNS servers are not required to respond with all A records for every query. There is no standard function to list local network interfaces so you'd end up relying on an extension or exec'ing system commands (e.g. `hostname --all-ip-addresses`). I suggest to clearly state that the webserver shouldn't accept requests for arbitrary hosts in your documentation and stick to a blacklist. Whatever you decide to do, take care that the check happens for redirects also, or disable redirects completely.

Comment: And keep in mind that there are many more [private addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) than just 127.0.0.1 and ::1. Symfony ships with [functions for checking IP addresses against subnets](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v4.2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/IpUtils.php) that you can borrow.